# Using Java library with Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm looking towards expanding an Android application written in Kotlin to iOS, and I would like to use Kotlin Multiplatform for that. But since I have one big Java dependency, which is BouncyCastle, I'm not sure it's possible. Are there any alternatives for BouncyCastle for Kotlin or a way to use java library with multiplatform?

Comment: you can use [Bouncy Castle Kotlin API and DSL Distribution](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-kotlin)

Comment: @SudheeshR this one is for Kotlin/JVM not Kotlin Native.

Comment: @Katherine if there is a C++ implementation for "BouncyCastle" then you can include it inside the Kotlin Native then share the code with all other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least assuming you are using Kotlin Native on iOS, your not going to be able to use Bouncy Castle. If your doing something a bit weirder, like using [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/) to distribute a Java based app, then the dependency should just work. Instead you'll need to use to crypto facilities provided by iOS or another library such as [CryptoSwift](https://cryptoswift.io/).

If your hoping to provide a common interface that can be used across multiple platforms, you can accomplish that with [platform specific declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html), but the actual implementation is going to have to vary based on the platform.